# JSF provide very basic REST get method

Tags: java, jsf, rest, servlets, get

Is there a way to have a doGet method in a `@ManagedBean` and define a URL on which this bean will react.

I am using JSF and want to provide a really basic feed, but for this I need to react on a get request.

I wrote it with normal servlets first, but now I noticed that I need information from another `ManagedBean` therefore I need a `@ManagedProperty` - hence JSF...

My questions:

- Is there a URLPattern annotation or similar?
- Is there a `doGet` method that is similar to the Servlet's `doGet`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming servlets...

If you're relying on the JSF [context](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html), the trick will be to get the [`FacesServlet`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html) to execute the code. The `FacesServlet` is responsible for creating and destroying the request context.

Here is the managed bean we want to invoke:

```
@ManagedBean @RequestScoped
public class Restlike {
  public void respond() {
   FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
   ExternalContext ext = context.getExternalContext();
   HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ext.getResponse();
   response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
    try {
      PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
      pw.print("Hello, World!");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new FacesException(ex);
    }
    context.responseComplete();
  }
}
```

Here is the placeholder view that will execute the code. `resty.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<metadata xmlns="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <event type="preRenderView" listener="#{restlike.respond}"/>
</metadata>
```

Hitting `resty.faces` doesn't look very RESTful, but it is trivial to handle with a [filter](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html):

```
@WebFilter("/rest/*")
public class RestyFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                       FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/resty.faces").forward(request, response);
  }

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

  @Override
  public void destroy() {} 
}
```

The resultant URL will look something like `http://host/context/rest`

---

This solution is a bit of a hack and only applicable to servlet environments. A better approach might be to add a custom [`ResourceHandler`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html) but I haven't spent much time investigating that part of the API.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a RESTful web service, use [JAX-RS](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#building-restful-web-services-with-jakarta-rest) (e.g. [Jersey](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html)) instead of JSF.

Or, if you just want "pretty" (REST-like) URLs for JSF, use [PrettyFaces](https://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/).

Comment: My app if heavly bases on JSF but now I need this feed, that is provided by a simple GET request. I only need one url an JSF not messing up my output so that I can write xml directly. But I have to access a JSF bean. This is the whole dilema. How can I get inforation of the ApllicationScoped bean

Comment: Then definitely use JAX-RS (you can just run it side by side with JSF in one webapp). That application scoped bean shall need to be refactored to something else which can be reused by both JAX-RS and JSF. For example, an EJB. Or you need CDI so that it can be injected in both JSF managed beans and JAX-RS web services. Or you can hack around by grabbing it as a `ServletContext` attribute.

Comment: Agree with @BalusC. If your requirements are 1. pretty URLs and 2. output is something other than html (e.g. xml), then JAX-RS might be the go. However, if you want pretty URLs in JSF 2, last time I checked PrettyFaces didn't work well with the more recent Mojarra implementations. If that's still the case, use UrlRewriteFilter instead. I use it and swear by it.